# Ruby - Check to see if specific int exists in an API response parameter

Tags: ruby, api, int, case, dst

In my response parameter, I am trying to take the `@start_date` (which is a DateTime variable so it is an `int`) and try to see whether it includes `11` in the date. 
The `@start_date` output is as follows:

```
2018-11-04 02:00:00 -0600
```

this is the case statement I am trying to wrap it in

```
  #begin case statement to see whether the shift length will go 
  #back/forward
  case
  when (@start_date.include?(11))
    season_logic = (60*60*9)
    puts "The date is a Fall date - The shift will go back one hour"
  when (@start_date.include?(3))
    season_logic = (60*60*7)
    puts "The date is a Spring date - The shift will go forward one hour "
  else
    raise "The season logic could not be calculated"
  end
    season_logic
```

however, I am getting an error saying this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'include?' for # . 
<DateTime:0x007fe5774957f0>
Did you mean?  include
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I wonder what you want to ensure by testing that a datetime contains an `11` at some position. Your example code would return _Fall date_ for the 11th of March. Is that really the result you expect? Shouldn't you be more specific and test the actual month of the date?

Comment: My question was sheerly out of why I kept getting that undefined method error, but yes you are absolutely correct and that was another implication I need to address once I get around to figuring that out. Do you have a suggestion for that? @spickermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String#include? looks to be what you're going for, which you can access if you convert the date to a string before invoking the method call and pass in '11' within a string context:

```
    when (@start_date.to_s.include?('11'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `@start_date` being a `DateTime` you can use the `month` method for your comparison:

```
case @start_date.month
when 3
  season_logic = (60*60*7)
  puts "The date is a Spring date - The shift will go forward one hour "
when 11
  season_logic = (60*60*9)
  puts "The date is a Fall date - The shift will go back one hour"
else
  raise "The season logic could not be calculated"
end
```